# How do you take your project from development to production?

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to you all,

I am currently developing a project on [Laravel](http://www.laravel.com). So far I have always developed online, directly editing my files on the webserver throuh FTP (using PSPad or similar simple editing tools).

What I want to do now (and what i believe most people actually do) is setup a (W)LAMP stack on my local machine and program locally. However it is a little bit unclear to me **how to keep my local code (including databases) in sync with the live website**. How do you folks do that? I know there's probably lots of ways and tools to do that, but what would be your advice for a best practice? Any advice would be very welcome :)

Comment: research `git`, Its what I use and its brilliant

Comment: I am downvoting this question for 2 reasons. 1. It has nothing to do with php. 2. It has nothing to do with laravel.

Comment: You are right itachi, unfortunately I couldn't find more appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What many companies do is build offline, then push their edits up to a server using [`git`](http://git-scm.com/).

Im no expert on the software so ill describe what you do in a basic form:

My advice would be to create an online repo (repository) to store your project while you edit/update.

There are several `git` project management systems such as [`github`](http://www.github.com) or [`bitbucket`](http://bitbucket.org). I personally use `bitbucket`

What `git` does, is when you have built or added what you need offline on local (w)lamp, you then `git push` them up to your repo or server. The changed files then get merged with the existing on the repo or the server. If you'd like the most recent version of your project you'd simply just `git pull` them down.

[Read the full documentation here](http://git-scm.com/documentation) to see the wide range of options available when using `git`

Answer (score 1):

We have a settings array within our platform available as $res::Config.

At runtime, a variable is changed from 'dev' to 'live' after checking the HTTP Host, obviously depending on the IP address.

Within our framework bootstrapping, depending on the value of $res::Config->$env, or the environment set previously as either dev or live, the settings for the database connection are set. You store these settings in the Config array as db_live or db_dev.

However you do it, use an environmental variable to figure out whether you want live or dev, and set up and array of settings accordingly.

We also have sandbox and staging for intermittent development stages.

As for version control, use git or subversion.

Edit: It's also possible that within our **vhost** file, we setup an environmental variable as either live or dev, and our application reads from this accordingly. I'd suggest this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this. But this is a deceptively HUGE question you've asked.
Here is some good practice advice - go and research these items, then have a look at my approach.

Typically you use a precess called version control which allows you to create "versions" or snapshots of your system. 
The commonly used "SVN" software is good, but the new (not really any more) kid on the block is GIT, and I personally recommend that.

You can use this system to push the codebase live in a controlled fashion. While the files/upload feature is essentially similar to FTP, it allows you to dump a specific version of your site live.

In environments where there are multiple developers, this is ideal - you can compare/test and work around each other, and version control tends to stop errors between devs.

So - advice part 1: Look up and understand version control, then use it to release CODE to the live environment.

Part 2: I use database dumps and farm them back to my machine to work with. 
If the live database needs updating, I can work locally and simply export, then re-import on the live system.

For example: on a recent Moodle project I worked on, to refresh the whole database took seconds... I could push a patch and database update in a few minutes.
However: you should think about maintenance and scheduling... if the site is live and has ongoing data changes then you need to be careful with this. Consider adding a maintenance page.

Advice 2: go research SQL dump/export and importing.

I personally use phpmyadmin to dump and re-import, as it's very convenient.

Advice 3: Working locally then pushing live is MUCH BETTER PRACTICE. You're starting down a much safer and better road than you're on!

Hope that helps... but bear in mind - this is a big subject, so you'll need to research a fair bit.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider what you wrote and dig into GIT!